# Looking for a MySQL Report Generator I can integrate into a web app

Tags: web-apps, php, mysql, reporting

I'm looking for a program that will allow a user to create a report from selected fields and tables in a mySQL database. The users won't know SQL commands, so it would all have to be done through a GUI. If possible, I would like to be able to integrate into an existing web application, rather than have a standalone application. So far, I think [Smart Report Maker](http://mysqlreports.com/mysql-reporting-tools/the-best-mysql-report-builder/) comes closest to meeting my needs. Does anyone have any experience with that tool?

The MySQL database is running on a Linux server. The users will be accessing the database from Windows computers.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MySQL reporting tools, but I've found this on the web: [10+ MySQL Reporting Tools](http://butleranalytics.com/10-mysql-reporting-tools/)

Comment: Thanks, but I already saw that list. That's actually where I found out about Smart Report Maker.

Comment: Is it a requirement that it runs on PHP? or can it run in another technology?

Comment: It has to run on PHP.